# How to resume activity when started from menu?

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

I am building an Android GPS application which contains many Activities. My main screen is a Google Maps screen which loads all the nearest locations from the remote database. I have other Activities which can be selected from the menu button e.g. List Mode, Add new location, Login, etc.

When I press on List Mode (or any other activity) and then start that Activity, and the press the physical back button on my phone, I am able to go back to my main screen which is my Map Activity without it restarting and reloading all the markers like it does on when the application starts up. My problem, however, is when I am in for example List Mode and then press the Map Mode from the Menu Options, it restarts the Maps activity such that it retrieves the locations all over again. I want to be able to press this Map Mode button and then resume it exactly like when I press the physical back button. How can I do this?

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the Maps activity? What Android class does it subclass? Does it contain onPause() and onResume(), and have you coded them so that the class saves and restores its state? Also, what Activity is controlling the menu itself?

Comment: try starting with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Let me know if it works, I am interested.

Comment: I tried Intent i = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're creating a new Map Activity and putting this new instance on top of the activity stack.

So your activity stack looks like this:

- **new** Map Activity
- List Activity
- **old** Map Activity

If I'm right, then pressing back from this 'new' Map Activity will bring you back to the List Activity. Pressing back again will bring you to the original Map Activity (the one you're looking for.

So, when you're in your List Activity, instead of staring a new Map Activity, you just simply would have to finish() that one.

Check out this document for further reading on intent flags:
[Intent Flags](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/)

Comment: How do I go into the Map Acitivty without starting it?

Comment: As I understand, you started the List Activity from your Map activity. So, if you close your List Activity - by calling finish(), you will be brought back to your original Map Activity.

Comment: Ooo, I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: Ok one question, what if I'm 2 (or however many) activities away from Map Activity? Say I am inside List Activity and I press a list item which would open up another Activity. How would I go back to Maps without restarting it?

Comment: Just tried finish() and it works but now I need to be able to do it when I've gone deeper into the application

Comment: There are several methods, one would be to call the List Activity with the flag set to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY. Or, you could call Map Activity again with the flag set to FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. As said, there are several ways to accomplish this. It's up to you to find which one suits your needs. Check the link about intent flags, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: So technically, if I just set REORDER_TO_FRONT in all my activities as a flag it should work?

Comment: aahh, I only want to resume an activity without restarting it where I am in the application. Nothing fancy

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this: [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). I had a similar type of app where I needed to "cache" the map data so that I would have to reload it. I used this as my reference.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest declare the launch mode of  the Map activity as singleInstance. Then I think you will be OK. From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode

Only allow one instance of this activity to ever be running. This activity gets a unique task with only itself running in it; if it is ever launched again with the same Intent, then that task will be brought forward and its Activity.onNewIntent() method called. If this activity tries to start a new activity, that new activity will be launched in a separate task. See the Tasks and Back Stack document for more details about tasks.

Comment: Can I do this for all activities?

Comment: what do you mean by this? clarify a little bit more.